# how to implement a list ADT in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

I am totally lost in my class right now and have no idea how to even start with this. I need to be able to create a list ADT called MyList that has a capacity of 2 and can hold only doubles. I need a constructor, accessor  getSize() and getItem(int idx), and mutator append, insert, and remove methods. i feel like if i can just get it started i can figure it out, i just do not know where to begin. Teacher says i have to use a one dimensional array. This is the code i have typed out thus far. Thanks

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyList
  {
  private int size;
  private double num;
  private MyList list;
  private Object data;

  double[] myList = new double[2];

  public MyList()
  {
    this.list = list;
    this.size = 2;
  }
  public int getSize()
  {
    return size;
  }
  public double getItem(int idx)
  {
    myList[i] =idx;
    return num;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your constructor and the `getItem` method as follows(comments inlined) -

```
private double num;
private MyList list; 
private Object data; // there isn't any use of this in the code

public MyList() {
    this.list = list
    this.size = myList.length;  // length of the list myList
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public double getItem(int idx) {
    this.num = myList[idx] // this would assign the value of element in `myList` at index `idx` to `num`
    return num; 
}
```